# 位置情報を取得するiPhoneAppを設定->位置情報の欄に表示させる方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

現在、位置情報を取得するiPhoneAppを作っています。

その為のコードを追加し、実行したのですが、設定の位置情報の欄にそのApp名が表示されません。

欄にApp名を表示させる方法と仕組みを教えてください。

なお、`Info.plist`に`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`と`NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription`は追加しています。

以下に、位置情報取得の為に追加したコードを載せます。

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
//位置情報メンバを定義
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

switch (status) {
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways: // アクセスが許可
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse: // アクセスを許可するか選択されていない

    {
        locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];//初期化
        locationManager.delegate=self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;//精度
        locationManager.distanceFilter=1.0;//更新頻度
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];//サービス開始
    }
        break;


    case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted: // 機能制限で利用が制限されている
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"エラー"
                                  message:@" 機能制限で利用が制限されています"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied: // 許可していない
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"エラー"
                                  message:@"アクセスを許可されていません"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
　　didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
　　NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation latitude=%f, longitude=%f, speed=%f, time=%@",
      [newLocation coordinate].latitude,
      [newLocation coordinate].longitude,
      newLocation.speed,
      newLocation.timestamp);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation ViewController
@synchronize locationManager;
```

インスタンス変数`locationManager`と、プロパティ`locationManager`をシンクロさせる必要があると思いますが、いかが？